# Naming a folder xxyyzz.download creates safari file?

Tags: macos, safari

I'm amazed that this is normal behaviour in OSX. But if you name your folder "xxxyyzz.download", it creates a temporary download file. This is not the only problem I encountered (there are other extensions that give problems), but I was wondering if this could be solved? I have a naming preference of using dots in the folders - seems this is not a good idea on OSX?

Comment: Using a . tends to create a bundle so yes not a good idea why not make each . into a new folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the bundle document type for the .download extension.

You'll have to edit */Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist* and remove the entry for the *download* extension under *Document Types*. The only disadvantage to this is that, whenever Safari updates, you'll have to do this again as your changes will be overridden.

I'd also make sure you make a backup of the Info.plist file first, before you make changes, incase you move the wrong line(s) or Safari gives you any issues after making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a dash instead of a period.
xxxyyzz-download